Text moving when I click my button in JavaFX
I'm trying to create a simple rock, paper, scissors program, and I have the basics down. The problem I'm facing at the moment is that, whenever I click either option (rock, paper or scissors) the "Computer" text above the picture of the randomly generated computer choice, moves when right to left and isn't aligned properly above the picture, making it a more ugly design than it already is, at this early stage.
I've tried looking into RowConstraints, but don't know how to apply it. I tried making the rows bigger and also the columns using ColumnConstraints, but it didn't seem to work (probably because I did it wrong).
Before I click one of the options

After I click it (Yes its ugly dont hate)

I have two other classes and a interface, which I can provide if needed. This is my main program:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class RockPaperScissors extends Application {
    static class Player{
        private final String username;
        private int score;

        public Player(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public int getScore() {
            return score;
        }

        public void setScore(int score) {
            this.score = score;
        }
    }
    
    static class ComputerPlayer extends Player {
        public Choice playTurn() {
            return Choice.values()
            [ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(
                            0, 
                    Choice.values().length
            )];
        }

        public ComputerPlayer(String username) {
            super(username);
        }
    }


    private Label playerNameLabel;
    private Label computerNameLabel;
    private Button rockButton;
    private Button paperButton;
    private Button scissorsButton;
    private Label resultLabel;
    private Player user;
    private ComputerPlayer computer;


    // A special class that holds three constant values. Rock, paper and sciccors. I can then call these values by the dot operator.
    public enum Choice {
        ROCK,
        PAPER,
        SCISSORS
    }

    // Create an ImageView object for the player and computer choice
    private StackPane playerChoiceImageView = new StackPane();
    private StackPane computerChoiceImageView = new StackPane();

    /**
     * Main method to start the game.
     *
     * @param args The command line arguments.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // Create the player and computer objects
        user = new Player("User");
        computer = new ComputerPlayer("Computer");
        // Set the title of the stage
        stage.setTitle("Rock, Paper, Scissors");

        // Create the labels for the player and computer names and make the text white
        playerNameLabel = new Label("Player");
        computerNameLabel = new Label("Computer");
        // Set the font family to "Arial" and the font weight to bold with a size of 20
        playerNameLabel.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));
        computerNameLabel.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));

        //playerNameLabel.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black;");
        //computerNameLabel.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black;");

        // Set the alignment and margins for the player label
        GridPane.setHalignment(playerNameLabel, HPos.LEFT);
        // Insets is a class that represents the distance between the edges of a node and its content.
        GridPane.setMargin(playerNameLabel, new Insets(10, 0, 15, 10));

        // Set the alignment and margins for the computer label
        GridPane.setHalignment(computerNameLabel, HPos.RIGHT);
        GridPane.setMargin(computerNameLabel, new Insets(5, 1, 15, 15));

        // Set the horizontal grow priority for the computer label, so it will expand if needed
        GridPane.setHgrow(computerNameLabel, Priority.ALWAYS);

        // Create the Rectangle objects for the buttons with a specified size
        Rectangle rockRectangle = createChoiceNode(Choice.ROCK);
        Rectangle paperRectangle = createChoiceNode(Choice.PAPER);
        Rectangle scissorsRectangle = createChoiceNode(Choice.SCISSORS);

        // Create the buttons with the Rectangle objects as their graphic
        rockButton = new Button("", rockRectangle);
        paperButton = new Button("", paperRectangle);
        scissorsButton = new Button("", scissorsRectangle);

        // Create the Label object for the result
        resultLabel = new Label();

        // Create the GridPane object with the game elements
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();

        // Add the player and computer choice ImageViews to the GridPane
        grid.add(playerChoiceImageView, 1, 2);
        grid.add(computerChoiceImageView, 6, 2);

        // Create the StackPane object and add the ImageView object to it
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        grid.add(playerNameLabel, 1, 1);
        grid.add(computerNameLabel, 5, 1);
        grid.add(rockButton, 3, 5);
        grid.add(paperButton, 4, 5);
        grid.add(scissorsButton, 5, 5);
        grid.add(resultLabel, 1, 6);

        // Add the GridPane object to the StackPane
        root.getChildren().add(grid);

        // Set the size of the StackPane to the size of the stage
        root.setPrefSize(stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight());


        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // Set the onAction handler for all buttons
        // The setOnAction() method is used to register an event handler for the onAction event, which is triggered when the button is clicked.
        //e -> handleButtonClick(Choice.ROCK"): This lambda expression creates an event handler for the rockButton.
        //When the rockButton is clicked, the lambda expression is executed, and the handleButtonClick method is called with the Choice.ROCK argument.
        rockButton.setOnAction(e -> handleButtonClick(Choice.ROCK));
        paperButton.setOnAction(e -> handleButtonClick(Choice.PAPER));
        scissorsButton.setOnAction(e -> handleButtonClick(Choice.SCISSORS));
    }

    private static @NotNull Rectangle createChoiceNode(Choice choice) {
        Rectangle rockRectangle = new Rectangle(60, 60);
        rockRectangle.setFill(switch (choice) { case ROCK -> Color.BROWN; case PAPER -> Color.ANTIQUEWHITE; case SCISSORS -> Color.DEEPPINK; });
        return rockRectangle;
    }

    private final List<Choice> choices = new ArrayList<>();

    private void handleButtonClick(Choice userChoice) {
        // Generate a random choice for the computer using the method from the ComputerPlayer class
        Choice computerChoice = computer.playTurn();

        // Update the images to show the choices the computer and the user made
        playerChoiceImageView.getChildren().add(createChoiceNode(userChoice));
        computerChoiceImageView.getChildren().add(createChoiceNode(computerChoice));

        // Store the choices in the ArrayList
        choices.add(userChoice);
        choices.add(computerChoice);

        // Determine the winner
        // Here I use the dot operator to call the special enum class Choice from before.
        if (userChoice == computerChoice) {
            // It is a tie
        } else if ((userChoice == Choice.ROCK && computerChoice == Choice.SCISSORS)
                || (userChoice == Choice.PAPER && computerChoice == Choice.ROCK)
                || (userChoice == Choice.SCISSORS && computerChoice == Choice.PAPER)) {
            // The player wins
            user.setScore(user.getScore() + 1);
        } else {
            // The computer wins
            computer.setScore(computer.getScore() + 1);
        }
        // Update resultLabel with the new scores
        resultLabel.setText("Player score: " + user.getScore() + "\n" +
                "Computer score: " + computer.getScore());
        // Set the font family to "Arial" and the font weight to bold with a size of 20
        resultLabel.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));
        //resultLabel.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black;");
    }
}


Off topic: You should never import awt classes, like java.awt.SystemColor.text in a JavaFX application unless you need them and know what you are doing.

Yeah that's an oopsie. I'm preeeeetty sure it doesn't do anything. I worked with awt in the start but switched to JavaFX

A single Grid for the entire UI is not the way to go here, IMO.  When an element in the grid changes size, everything else will shift. Instead, use the best-fit layout managers for each portion of the UI.  I encourage you to download SceneBuilder and experiment with that.  It is, IMO, a quicker and more efficient way to learn different UI layouts and experiment with them (even if you end up not using FXML at all).  SceneBuilder will default the preferred sizes for layout panes, remove those to let the scene auto-resize to your layout.

I updated the code in your question so that it can run just through copy and paste, if it differs from your intentions, then revert or edit it.

The Oracle JavaFX layout tutorial is still the best resource around for working with JavaFX layouts.  Even though it is for the older JavaFX 8 system, the core layout concepts have never changed since JavaFX was initially released.  Trying to base a complex UI around a GridPane is difficult.  It only really works well if the thing you are laying out in a grid has a natural grid-like structure which does not change.

I can not use scenebuilder, since the requirements of my project, is that the GUI has to be done manually in JavaFX

And I tried to copy paste your code into my class, but it does the same thing as mine. Shifts the "computer" text from right to left

"And I tried to copy paste your code into my class, but it does the same thing as mine. Shifts the "computer" text from right to left" -> I know that. I am not offering a solution for your assignment, all I did was update the code in your question so that it compiled and replicated the issue through copy and paste so that others could help if they wanted.

"I can not use scenebuilder, since the requirements of my project, is that the GUI has to be done manually in JavaFX" -> I am not suggesting that you use SceneBuilder for your assignment.  I am suggesting that you use it to learn how layout works.

One way to implement this using a GridPane, and in a way that nothing moves, is to add everything you might need to the scene at startup, with the parts you don't want to see initially having visible=false.  The layout will be computed including all the non-visible nodes. Then in your event handlers, toggle the visibility to keep the UI in sync with the state of the game.

That said, if you are going to use JavaFX, I strongly recommend learning how the layout system works and how different layout panes behave, as recommended by @jewelsea.

Thanks for the suggestions. Big help!

Late to the game here, but GridPane is good when everything needs to line up in row and column form without exceptions.  Once you get away from this it starts to become a pain.  If it was me, I'd use a BorderPane and put the three images in the center.  Then an AnchorPane in the top the Player/Computer choices anchored to the left and right sides.  Then I'd put the results in a VBox in the bottom section of the BorderPane.  The player/computer choices can be Labels, with the graphic() controlled via the choices.

As stated in the comments, you need to master the layout nodes. In this case, I think BorderPane would be the best root node. This example I created uses VBox as the root node because I like to use VBox as the root node. There are probably better ways to do this using other nodes. Also, as stated in the comments, using SceneBuilder can help you figure out the settings to get the nodes laid out exactly how you like. In code, I try to divide my GUI into sections and work on each section as I go.
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
 
public class App extends Application {
 
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        //Top
        //Left Top
        Label lblPlayer = new Label("Player");
        Button btnPlayer = new Button("Button");
        VBox vbLeftTop = new VBox(lblPlayer, btnPlayer);
        //Settings
        lblPlayer.setFont(Font.font("System", FontWeight.BOLD, 16));
        btnPlayer.setPrefSize(90, 75);
        vbLeftTop.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        
        //Center Top
        Pane panePlaceHolder = new Pane();
        //Settings
        HBox.setHgrow(panePlaceHolder, Priority.ALWAYS);
        
        //Right Top
        Label lblComputer = new Label("Computer");
        Button btnComputer = new Button("Button");
        VBox vbRightTop = new VBox(lblComputer, btnComputer);
        //Setting
        lblComputer.setFont(Font.font("System", FontWeight.BOLD, 16));
        btnComputer.setPrefSize(90, 75);
        vbRightTop.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);        
        
        //Top root
        HBox hbTopRoot = new HBox(vbLeftTop, panePlaceHolder, vbRightTop);
        //Settings
        VBox.setMargin(hbTopRoot, new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10));
        
        
        //Center 
        Pane panePlaceHolderTwo = new Pane();        
        Button btnOne = new Button("Button");
        Button btnTwo = new Button("Button");
        Button btnThree = new Button("Button");
        Pane panePlaceHolderThree = new Pane();        
        //Settings
        HBox.setHgrow(panePlaceHolderTwo, Priority.ALWAYS);
        btnOne.setPrefSize(90, 75);
        btnTwo.setPrefSize(90, 75);
        btnThree.setPrefSize(90, 75);
        HBox.setHgrow(panePlaceHolderThree, Priority.ALWAYS);
        
        //Center root
        HBox hbCenterRoot = new HBox(panePlaceHolderTwo, btnOne, btnTwo, btnThree, panePlaceHolderThree);
        //Settings
        VBox.setMargin(hbCenterRoot, new Insets(20, 10, 0, 10));
        
        //Bottom
        //Botton one
        Label lblPlayerScore = new Label("Player Score:");
        Label lblPlayerScoreCount = new Label("0");
        HBox hbOne = new HBox(lblPlayerScore, lblPlayerScoreCount);
        //Settings
        lblPlayerScore.setFont(Font.font("System", FontWeight.NORMAL, 24));
        lblPlayerScoreCount.setFont(Font.font("System", FontWeight.NORMAL, 24));
        hbOne.setMaxWidth(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        hbOne.setSpacing(5);
        //Bottom two
        Label lblComputerScore = new Label("Computer Score:");
        Label lblComputerScoreCount = new Label("0");
        HBox hbTwo = new HBox(lblComputerScore, lblComputerScoreCount);
        //Settings
        lblComputerScore.setFont(Font.font("System", FontWeight.NORMAL, 24));
        lblComputerScoreCount.setFont(Font.font("System", FontWeight.NORMAL, 24));
        hbTwo.setMaxWidth(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        hbTwo.setSpacing(5);
        
        
        //Bottom root
        VBox vbBottomRoot = new VBox(hbOne, hbTwo);
        //Settings
        vbBottomRoot.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        VBox.setVgrow(vbBottomRoot, Priority.ALWAYS);
        vbBottomRoot.setPadding(new Insets(20, 0, 0, 0));
        
        VBox root = new VBox(hbTopRoot, hbCenterRoot, vbBottomRoot);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400); 
        stage.setScene(scene); 
        stage.show();
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        launch(args);
    }
}

Output


That is exactly how i want it to look! That is cool. I might want to try using a Borderpane then! I'm not familiar with alot of the words like "hb" and "vb" but ill try to make sense of it and use some of that for guidance. Very nice, thank you!

hb and vb are just little naming conventions that I like to use to help me know what kind of node I am dealing with later in the code. Let's say I have a Label and a TextField I want to associate with name.  I would do something like Label lblName = new Label("Name"); TextField tfName = new TextField(); and then later in the code, I may need to update the TextField. I can easily know which one I need to update. tfName.setText("...");
